# How is Intercom.io storing users cookies on Safari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, safari, intercom

Safari has a strict 'no 3rd party cookie, unless user has been to that site and stored it' rule.

So how is intercom.io's chat able to store users cookies?

Their language: Ruby on rails